# Alternatives inline interface implementation in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, interface

I'd like to use inline interface implementation in C# but reading some posts like this or this I found out that it's not like Java do it.

Supposing this interface:

```
public interface MyListener {
    void onHandleOne();
    void onHandleTwo();
    }
```

and I pass this interface as a parameter:

```
   myMethod(MyListener listener){
    //some logic
   }
```

and when I call it I'd like to do inline imlementation like in java:

```
myMethod(new MyListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onHandleOne() {
                        //do work
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHandleTwo() {
                        //do work
                    }
                });
```

As an alternative I made a class that implements yhis interface and use this class to call my method:

```
public class MyImplementor : MyListener  {
    public void onHandleOne() {
        //do work
        }

    public void onHandleTwo() {
        //do work
        }
    }
```

and call my method:  `myMethod(new MyImplementor())` 
but this solutions needs a new class every time I'll call this method (for different behavior) maybe is there a way using lambda or somehow to do it like:

`myMethod(new MyImplementor() =>{//handle my methods})`

Comment: You want different implementations of `onHandleOne` and `onHandleTwo` , don't you?

Comment: Make the `MyImplementor` class take in instances of [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) in the constructor and store them in private fields. Then invoke such actions in the methods.

Comment: On .net the standard pattern is to use events. Java does not use this pattern because Java does not have delegates nor events, events are more flexible than listeners.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but this solutions needs a new class every time I'll call this method
>   (for different behavior) maybe is there a way using lambda or somehow
>   to do it like

Yes, give it a delegate parameter and pass it a lambda.

```
public class MyImplementor : MyListener  
{
    private readonly Action handle1;
    private readonly Action handle2;
    public MyImplementor(Action handle1, Action handle2)
    {
        this.handle1 = handle1;
        this.handle2 = handle2;
    }

    public void onHandleOne() 
    {
       handle1();
    }

    public void onHandleTwo()
    {
       handle2();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
myMethod(new MyImplementor(()=>{//handle method1}, ()=>{//Handle method2});
```

Comment: Not good, the signature is usually given (3rd party), and  it wants an interface. So I cannot change it to delegate.